# Lazy load spring bean

Tags: java, spring

If a bean is lazily loaded, Will all the beans defined inside the lazily loaded beans will be lazily loaded? (even though they are not defined @Lazy)

Here is the test project:
https://github.com/madhur/conditional-property-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/EventPublishService.java

I have these beans:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        name = {"publish.feed.events"},
        havingValue = "true"
)
public class EventPublishService {
 
     @Autowired
     private KafkaPublisher kafkaPublisher;

}
```

////////////////////

```
@Service
public class EventService {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private EventPublishService eventPublishService;

    @Value("${publish.feed.events:false}")
    private boolean isPublishEvents;
}
```

/////////////////////////

```
@Component
public class KafkaPublisher {

    @Value("${kafka.producer.financial_feed.topic}")
    private String financeFeedTopic;
}
```

Any my application.properties has just one property,

```
publish.feed.events=false
```

Since , I am not loading `EventPublishService` beans(because the property is false), I expect the dependency bean `KafkaPublisher` should not be loaded as well. However, I get the error upon startup, which means the `KafkaPublisher` bean is getting loaded, even though `EventPublishService` bean is not getting loaded.

How can I ensure that `KafkaPublisher` bean should not be loaded?
And thus property should not be mandatory required for anyone not requiring `EventPublishService` bean?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaPublisher': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'kafka.producer.financial_feed.topic' in value "${kafka.producer.financial_feed.topic}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:379) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17) [main/:na] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'kafka.producer.financial_feed.topic' in value "${kafka.producer.financial_feed.topic}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:839) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: They will be loaded at the same time at which the lazily loaded bean is loaded, if not otherwise specified.

Comment: I am not seeing this behaviour. The other transitive beans are loaded anyways.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja just curious, did my answer not help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [stated in the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-dependency-resolution),

> Beans that are singleton-scoped and set to be pre-instantiated (the default) are created when the container is created

thus it doesn't matter if you put `@Lazy` on `@Autowired`, the bean will be created at startup **as long as the bean itself is not defined lazy**:

```
@Component
public class KafkaPublisher {
    ...
}
```

**If you want this bean to be lazily initialized, put** `@Lazy` **on it**. If you want the process of bean injection to be lazy, put `@Lazy` on `@Autowired`, as simple as that.

Lazily initializing a set of related beans could be achieved by declaring them inside a `@Configuration` class and marking configuration `@Lazy`. However, note that ALL of the declared beans will be initialized as soon as `@Configuration` class is initialized.

```
@Lazy
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(...) // will be lazily initialized with config
public class LazyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SomeBean beanName() { // will be lazily initialized with config
        return new SomeBean();
    } 

    @Bean
    public OtherBean beanName() { // will be lazily initialized with config
        return new OtherBean();
    }     
}
```

However, when using `@ComponentScan`, make sure the beans (i.e `@Service`, `@Component`, etc) you want to initialize lazily are not already scanned by some other context. If they are, add them as exclusions to scanning for that context.

---

**Outdated answer down below, for historical purposes (before OP completely changed the question):**

Declaring beans inside beans is not considered to be a good practice, but if you mark a `@Configuration` as lazy, then indeed all the beans inside of it will be lazily initialized, as stated in `@Lazy`'s javadoc:

> If Lazy is present on a @Configuration class, this indicates that all
>   @Bean methods within that @Configuration should be lazily initialized.

If by **"beans defined inside"** you actually mean injection points, such as `@Autowired`, javadoc has the answer for that as well:

> Lazy annotation may also be placed on injection points marked with
>   Autowired or Inject: In that context, it leads to the creation of a
>   lazy-resolution proxy for all affected dependencies, as an alternative
>   to using ObjectFactory or Provider.

However, the actual autowired bean will be initialized eagerly (if not marked as @Lazy as well). It's the injection itself that will be lazy in this case.

Otherwise, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Just a reminder: all beans (if not @lazy) are initialized upon context creation. I assume you know and understand that.

Comment: Please see the details added above.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja updated the answer. Tell me if it's clear enough or if I need to clarify something

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way to lazy load entire set of related beans other than putting lazy on each of them.

Comment: It did. But looking for other people opinion always helps.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja why not award bounty though? It's a minor thing, and I'm not asking for it, just seems wierd, especially for someone with your amount of reputation. Basic politeness

Comment: It will be automatically awarded at the expiration.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja not sure, since my answer was posted before you offered the bounty. Whatever, at least I helped, and that’s what matters. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work