# Why lazy loading works without @Lazy on @Component

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading, spring-annotations, lazy-initialization

I have a Spring `@Component` which is added as a dependency in another class with the annotation `@Lazy`. As per https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation , https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/core/spring-bean-eager-vs-lazy-init/ , https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041333/6923588 the `@Component` itself should be annotated with `@Lazy` in order to work. But with the following code it seems to work without adding the @Lazy annotation.

Lazy component interface.

```
public interface Lazzy {
    public void doSome();
}
```

Lazy component implementation.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
// @Lazy // annotation is commented out
public class LazzyImpl implements Lazzy {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LazzyImpl.class);

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        logger.debug("in init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSome() {
        logger.debug("am called");

    }
}
```

Runner class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/test-context.xml" })
public class LazyTest {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LazyTest.class);

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private Lazzy lazzy;

    @Test
    public void test_Lazy() {
        logger.debug("in test_Lazzy");
        // lazy.doSome(); // intentionally commented out to check whether LazzyImpl is initialized or not
        logger.debug("in test_Lazzy over");
    }
}
```

When I run this, I see the following.

```
LazyTest.test_Lazy(LazyTest.java:25) - in test_Lazzy
LazyTest.test_Lazy(LazyTest.java:27) - in test_Lazzy over
```

If I take off `@Lazy` on `private Lazzy lazzy;` with `lazy.doSome();` still commented out, I see following (as expected).

```
LazzyImpl.init(LazzyImpl.java:17) - in init
LazyTest.test_Lazy(LazyTest.java:25) - in test_Lazzy
LazyTest.test_Lazy(LazyTest.java:27) - in test_Lazzy over
```

Question:
Why is this code working (i.e. lazy initialized) without `@Lazy` annotation on `LazzyImpl` along with `@Component`?

The given example is using Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE version.

Comment: you can control lazy-initialization at the container level by using the default-lazy-init.  Do you have any such configuration in your test-context.xml.  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Comment: thanks for your input @JerinJoseph. 1. i cannot use the default-lazy-init you suggested, since my Spring is 4.0.3. 2. am not looking for a way to make this work, my question is "why lazy loading works despite not following instructions given in the provided URLs"